# Security implications of storing email attachments on Centos Server

Tags: mysql, apache, security, centos, email-attachments

There is an application I am working on which requires processing the incoming mails to **cs@company.com**.
The **company.com** mail accounts are being run via **Google Apps for Business**.
So I fetch the incoming mails via **IMAP** and I also store the attachments on the server filesystem.
Attachments are downloadable by the users of the application.
Server is **Centos 6.3** and the web interface of the application is based on Apache/PHP/MySql.

My questions are :
 1. What kind of security risks I am exposed to by storing the attachments on my server filesystem?
 2. Is it safer to store the attachments to an external storage (for e.g. **Amazon S3**)?
3. Is it safer to store the attachments in the DB?